# Need help finding socket adapter for ROM chip

Tags: components, socket, rom

I have this ROM chip that I need to program without having to solder onto a board:

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/adesto-technologies/AT25SL321-MBUE-T/6827495

Will this socket adapter work?

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/3m/208-7391-55-1902/1130108

I mostly need to make sure that the socket will work with that ROM chip's package (8-UDFN)

Comment: Re: the votes to close here - I'm often one of the 1st to VTC shopping questions, but I'm not reading this as one of those. he OP has already gone shopping and chosen a part, but isn't sure if they've chosen correctly and is asking for some help with verification.

Comment: It looks to me as though that socket is similar to ones I've used before which rely on the leads of the device to align it correctly over the contacts in the socket - there are little 'fingers' between each contact which force the leads of the device into position. With a leadless UDFN device I don't think that this mechanism will work as well so you might have trouble with alignment when placing the part into the socket.

Comment: https://www.reveltronics.com/en/shop/75/7/chip-programmers/adapter-dfn8-2x3-udfn8-vson8-uson8-dil8-dip8-75-detail

Comment: RGB Engineer, despite the question being closed unfairly (in my opinion), I have given an answer and, in all fairness to me, if there is a problem, it would be wise to leave a comment or, proceed down the route of finishing the session in the normal acceptable way.

Comment: RGB Engineer - do you need clarification on any info in my answer. In short; don't discard this question because it once became unfairly closed. I'm trying to support you on this.

Answer (score 0):

> *Will this socket adapter work?*

The socket adapter is for SOIC chips and they have a pin-spacing of 1.27 mm. The pin-spacings for 8-UDFN devices appear to be 0.5 mm or 0.65 mm as per [this document from Microchip](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/PackagingSpec/00000049BQ.pdf). I don't see any UDFN devices with pin-spacings greater than 0.65 mm.

[Shrink small-outline package (SSOP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_outline_integrated_circuit) can have a pitch of 0.65 mm but I don't believe these will be compatible with your adapter either.

Ditto many MSOP, TSSOP and µSOP devices as per [this wiki site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrated_circuit_packaging_types).